# When the default text-to-speech program (spd-say) speaks it is accompanied by noise/crackling/buzzing (and some echo), how to fix?

Tags: sound, text-to-speech

```
spd-say "Hello world!"
```

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop (Dell XPS 15). I haven't noticed any audio problems on this machine with any other application. I've done `sudo apt dist-upgrade` pretty recently so everything is pretty much up to date.

```
> lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

> spd-say --version
spd-say: 0.8.7
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Brailcom, o.p.s.

> uname -sr
Linux 4.13.0-39-generic
```

The problem persists if I change the volume on the computer, but if I run the application *randomly a couple of times* with the parameters `-i -50` (decreased volume) it goes away *temporarily*, but I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the combination of speech-dispatcher with pulseaudio. As a workaround you can set

```
AudioOutputMethod "libao"
```

in `/etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf`.

(Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215987)